# I can't delete nor insert data in my database through webservice using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, postgresql

Here is my test_database.html page

```
<html>
<head> 
<title> <h1> Database Test </h1> </title>
<script>

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else 
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            {
                var xmlObj = xmlhttp.responseXML;

                var textXML = xmlObj.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;


                if (window.DOMParser)
                {
                    parser=new DOMParser();
                    var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(textXML,"text/xml");
                }
                else // Internet Explorer
                {
                    var xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async=false;
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(textXML);
                }   
                var rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("row");
                mybody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                mytable=document.createElement("table");
                mytablebody=document.createElement("tbody");
                //alert(cols.length);
                for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
                {   mycurrent_row=document.createElement("tr"); 
                    var cols=rows[i].getElementsByTagName("colunm");

                   for(var j=0; j<cols.length; j++) 
                    {     mycurrentcell=document.createElement("td");  
                          currenttext=document.createTextNode(cols[j].getAttribute("colvalue"))
                          mycurrentcell.appendChild(currenttext);
                          mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrentcell);  
                     }  
                                     mycurrent_row.id=cols[0].getAttribute("colvalue");
                         mybutoncell = document.createElement("td");
                         but=document.createElement("input");
                         but.type="button";
                         mybutoncell.appendChild(but);                                      
                         mycurrent_row.appendChild(mybutoncell); 
                         mytablebody.appendChild(mycurrent_row);
                         but.onclick=ajaxDBDelete;
                }
                mytable.appendChild(mytablebody);
                mybody.appendChild(mytable);
                 mytable.setAttribute("border","2");    
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1:8080/axis2/services/database_tmm_man/SelectFromDB?",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }       
    function ajaxDBInsert ()
    { 
     var textvalue= document.getElementById('txbegn').value
       var xml="<university><student>";
       xml+="<egn>" +textvalue+ "</egn>";
       xml+="<fname>" + document.getElementById('txbfname').value + "</fname>";
       xml+="<mname>" + document.getElementById('txbmidname').value + "</mname>" ;
       xml+="<lname>" + document.getElementById('txblname').value + "</lname>";
       xml+="<telnum>" + document.getElementById ('txbtelnum').value + "</telnum>";
       xml+="</student></university>";

    alert(xml);
    var tranXml = escape(xml); 
    alert(tranXml);

        var url = "localhost/services/database_tmm_man/InsertInto?";
        var params = "data=" + tranXml;
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(params);   


    }

    function ajaxDBDelete()
    {
          var par=this.parentNode;
          while(par.nodeName.toLowerCase()!='tr')
          {
              par=par.parentNode;
          }
          alert (par.id);
         var delid="<university><student>";
         delid+= "<egn>" + par.id + "</egn>";
         delid+= "</student></university>";
         alert(delid);
         var tranDelid = escape(delid);
         alert (tranDelid);

        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/axis2/services/database_tmm_man/DeleteFromDB?";
        var params = "deleteID=" + tranDelid;
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(params);   
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadXMLDoc();">

EGN:                  <input type="text" id="txbegn"/><br>
FIRST NAME:           <input type="text" id="txbfname"/><br>
MIDDLE NAME:          <input type="text" id="txbmidname"/><br>
LAST NAME:            <input type="text" id="txblname"/><br>
Telephone Number:     <input type="text" id="txbtelnum"/><br>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" name="btnInsert" onClick="ajaaclxDBInsert();">INSERT</button>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code for my service

```
package gismo;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.*; 

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;


public class database_tmm_man 

{

    Connection conn= null;
    String strEgnin;
    String strFname;
    String strMname;
    String strLname;
    String strNumtel;
    String strEgndel;

public String SelectFromDB()
{

    String strXml = "<response>";


        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try 
        {
            conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/plovdivbizlocator", "postgres", "********");
        } 

        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Statement mystmt = null;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT egn, firstname, middlename, lastname,telnumber FROM tanya_students";
        try 
        {
            mystmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet mysr = mystmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);  

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = mysr.getMetaData(); 
            int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                int numberrow=0;

            strXml += "<rows>";
            while (mysr.next())
            {  
                strXml += "<row id= '"+numberrow +"'>";
                for (int i=1;i<=colCount;i++) 
                {
                    String elementname = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                    String elementValue=mysr.getString(i);
                    strXml += "<colunm colname='"+elementname+"' colvalue='"+elementValue+"'/>";
                }                   
                numberrow++;
                strXml +="</row>";
            }
            strXml += "</rows>";                

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}
        strXml+="</response>";

        return strXml;


}


public String InsertIntoDB (String data) throws ClassNotFoundException
{

    try
        {   String strDecodedData = URLDecoder.decode(data);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dbBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dbBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(strDecodedData.getBytes("utf-8"))));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
            int num=nList.getLength();
            for (int i=0;i<num;i++)
                        {       
                            Element section=(Element)nList.item(i);                     
                            strEgnin = section.getElementsByTagName("egn").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();              
                            strFname = section.getElementsByTagName("fname").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();             
                            strMname = section.getElementsByTagName("mname").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();            
                            strLname = section.getElementsByTagName("lname").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();                
                            strNumtel =section.getElementsByTagName("telnum").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                        }
        }

    catch (Exception ex1)
         {

         }

    Connection conn= null;

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    try 
    {
        conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:/127.0.0.1:5432/plovdivbizlocator", "postgres", "********");
    } 

    catch (SQLException ex) 
        {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String insertQuery= "insert into tanya_students (egn, firstname, middlename, lastname, telnumber)";
    insertQuery +="values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try
        {
            pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            pstmt.setString(1,strEgnin);
            pstmt.setString(2,strFname);
            pstmt.setString(3,strMname);
            pstmt.setString(4,strLname);
            pstmt.setString(5,strNumtel);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }

    catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    return "" ;
}
public String DeleteFromDB(String deleteID) 
{
    try
    {   String strDecodeddelID = URLDecoder.decode(deleteID);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dbBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dbBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(strDecodeddelID.getBytes("utf-8"))));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
        int num=nList.getLength();
        for (int i=0;i<num;i++)
                    {       
                        Element section=(Element)nList.item(i);                     
                        strEgndel = section.getElementsByTagName("egn").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();                 


                    }
    }

catch (Exception ex1)
     {

     }






  Connection conn= null;

    try 
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } 

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {
        conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:/127.0.0.1:5432/plovdivbizlocator", "postgres", "********");
    } 

    catch (SQLException ex) 
        {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    PreparedStatement delstmt = null;
    String delQuery= "DELETE FROM tanya_students WHERE egn= ?";
    try
        {
            delstmt=conn.prepareStatement(delQuery);
            delstmt.setString(1,strEgndel);
            delstmt.executeUpdate();
        }

    catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    return "" ;

}




}
```

just when I try to delete a record when I click on the button at the end of each row just nothing happens. It may be useful to mention that I choose for my row.id the first column of my database - egn which is unique (there are no people with same egn). That's why I'm sending this egn to the server and my webservice
In void main programme everythins works poerfect@\ so i think that somehow I'm not sending properly the data to my server

the same with insert - when i type some data in the textboxes which i want to insert into the database and when i click the insert button  nothing happens
thanks for the help in advance

Comment: try putting some error handling in your catch() statements, perhaps?

    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
      ex1.printStackTrace();
    }

maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain that your Ajax call is being made properly or at all? Since you are constructing the call in raw Javascript have you tested it in multiple browsers? There are some good Chrome extensions that allow you to construct REST calls by hand to test whether the webservice is working correctly out of the browser document context. (I use a program called Graphic HHTP client, but I think it is Mac-only).

Doing this would at least help you determine whether the issue is server-side or client-side.

Comment: Actually I'm almost sure that my ajax call is not moade properly! Because I have tested my server side code and as I wrote it works perfect! I think the problem is in the call! I'm doing this for the first time and I don't know how to test it because that's the only thing I' haven't tested

Comment: I would use something like JQuery to do ajax calls in stead of rolling your own if I were you; error handling is built in then.

Comment: I didn't want to say it, but I agree with Gimby that if you are just starting out you are much better off using a library to handle the difference in browser implementations. (even if you not just starting out I'd still says its better, why reinvent the wheel?).

Comment: yes I understand but my task is to do it with javascript! there is no other way!

Comment: Helo I wanted to say that I solved the problem! Instead of post i used the GET method!